# How to draw rectangles box over the image uploaded in React

Tags: reactjs, upload, shapes, drawrectangle

I have got some issues to draw rectangles box onto the image uploaded. Now my code can let the user draw the rectangles box onto the displayed image but I don't know how to do it with the image uploaded. Can someone help me with Reactjs?

My code is below or you can find in the link here, easy to see what I mean
https://codesandbox.io/s/draw-shape-olnv6?file=/src/index.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {
  ShapeEditor,
  ImageLayer,
  DrawLayer,
  wrapShape,
} from 'react-shape-editor';
import upload_icon from './asset/floor.jpg';

function arrayReplace(arr, index, item) {
  return [
    ...arr.slice(0, index),
    ...(Array.isArray(item) ? item : [item]),
    ...arr.slice(index + 1),
  ];
}

const RectShape = wrapShape(({ width, height }) => (
  <rect width={width} height={height} fill="rgba(0,0,255,0.5)" />
));

let idIterator = 1;

const Editor = () => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([
    { id: '1', x: 20, y: 120, width: 145, height: 140 },
    { id: '2', x: 15, y: 0, width: 150, height: 95 },
  ]);
  let [file, setFile] = useState(null);

  const [{ vectorHeight, vectorWidth }, setVectorDimensions] = useState({
    vectorHeight: 0,
    vectorWidth: 0,
  });

  const uploadIconStyle = {
    display: 'inline',
    width: 500,
    height: 500,
  };

  const fileChangedHandler = (event) => {
    let file = event.target.files[0];
    let reader = new FileReader();
    console.log(file);
    reader.onload = function (e) {
      setFile(e.target.result);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        className="btn btn-secondary"
        id="fileInput"
        type="file"
        accept="image/*"
        onChange={fileChangedHandler}
      />
      <img
        src={file}
        alt={''}
        width="400"
        height="400"
        text-align="left"
        style={{ display: 'block' }}
      />
      <ShapeEditor vectorWidth={vectorWidth} vectorHeight={vectorHeight}>
        <ImageLayer
          // Photo by Sarah Gualtieri on Unsplash
          style={uploadIconStyle}
          src={upload_icon}
          responsive
          onLoad={({ naturalWidth, naturalHeight }) => {
            setVectorDimensions({
              vectorWidth: naturalWidth,
              vectorHeight: naturalHeight,
            });
          }}
        />
        <DrawLayer
          onAddShape={({ x, y, width, height }) => {
            setItems((currentItems) => [
              ...currentItems,
              { id: `id${idIterator}`, x, y, width, height },
            ]);
            idIterator += 1;
          }}
        />
        {items.map((item, index) => {
          const { id, height, width, x, y } = item;
          return (
            <RectShape
              key={id}
              shapeId={id}
              height={height}
              width={width}
              x={x}
              y={y}
              onChange={(newRect) => {
                setItems((currentItems) =>
                  arrayReplace(currentItems, index, {
                    ...item,
                    ...newRect,
                  })
                );
              }}
              onDelete={() => {
                setItems((currentItems) =>
                  arrayReplace(currentItems, index, [])
                );
              }}
            />
          );
        })}
      </ShapeEditor>
    </div>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById('root');
ReactDOM.render(<Editor />, rootElement);
```

Comment: I think the problem you are facing of drawing on top of an uploaded img is relevant for all types of HTML tags that aren't placed inside the ShapeEditor. Even if the img has not resolved from a file upload, and is hardcoded on the application, the rect would still not hover on top of it. same for a text tag, the rect wouldn't draw when hovering it.

Have you considered using ImageLayer for the fileinput-img as well and place it inside the ShapeEditor? I think that would work.

Comment: @Shimi updated the code on the link codesandbox above but it does not work, could you help?